# How can we use dot/bullet point in edittext with bigger size as a hint in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I have used \u2022 in strings.xml file. It shows the dots in too small size. How to increase the hint text size or how to make the dots size bigger?

Comment: If you want to handle it in the XML, you could wrap it in one or more `<big>` elements: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML. Unfortunately, I think that's about all you can do there. If you need finer control over the size, I'm pretty sure at least part of it has to be done in code, as demonstrated in the next couple of sections on that page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithSpannables.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spannable text
[refer this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568) for code snippets